# does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write' at scope

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-eventgrid

[image]
I'm getting this error when trying to connect Event Grid from ADX to ingest data into adx tables.

what are permissions I need to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have sufficient permissions to deploy an EG subscription.
I would guess you need to be the storage account or subscription owner/contributor.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer! as I have limited access to the adls storage account, I can only access there through SP, so to deploy the EG subscription, do I need to be an owner of the storage account or have the access permission to the whole storage account?

Comment: yes (sorry for the late answer)